# Low the brightness of an Image using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow for a project, and I really want to create an effect like in the following Image, look:

[image: To Throw a chicken at oneself]

In this picture, you see like the background Image is opaque, I don't know if that's the word I need to use. What I want to do is that the text is brighter than the background Image, this is a nice effect.

Can I duplicate this effect in Pillow? and if so, what would be the function? Thank you a lot. I know this is a broad question, but since I don't know how to even ask the question the proper way, I will accept any suggestion that will lead me to the right path.

PS. I found this picture at: http://qz.com/402739/the-best-idioms-from-around-the-world-ranked/

Comment: See question [_Algorithm to modify brightness for RGB image?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163578/algorithm-to-modify-brightness-for-rgb-image) The answer suggesting the multiplication of each of the image's R,G,B values by some constant would be practical to implement with Pillow via the `Image.point()` function. The one suggesting the conversion of each pixel from RGB to HSL and then back would likely be impractical to do using it although it could be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment of @martineau

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image-to-modify.jpg')

source = im.split()

R, G, B = 0, 1, 2
constant = 1.5 # constant by which each pixel is divided

Red = source[R].point(lambda i: i/constant)
Green = source[G].point(lambda i: i/constant)
Blue = source[B].point(lambda i: i/constant)

im = Image.merge(im.mode, (Red, Green, Blue))

im.save('modified-image.jpeg', 'JPEG', quality=100)
```

Answer (score 10):

As stated [in the docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html) you can use Pillow's `ImageEnhance` module for lowering or increasing the brightness of an image.

Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

img = Image.open("image.jpg")
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
# to reduce brightness by 50%, use factor 0.5
img = enhancer.enhance(0.5)

img.show()
img.save("image_darker.jpg")
```

So to get the text of the image brighter than the background image, first apply the effect to the image, then add the text.

Comment: 6 years ago the job well done, thx!