# Combine arrays to raster (jpeg)

Tags: python, image, numpy, gdal, python-imaging-library

I am trying all day combine three ndarrays to one jpeg picture. I extract three bands using gdal library. Exported values are in array, looks like this:

```
[[ 6355.  6586.  6646. ...,   704.   671.   725.]
 [ 5853.  6031.  6107. ...,   782.   813.   897.]
 [ 4632.  4748.  4305. ...,   837.   869.   802.]
 ..., 
 [ 1032.  1090.  1018. ...,  1500.  1441.  1387.]
 [  958.   980.   913. ...,  1522.  1455.  1391.]
 [  883.   932.   966. ...,  1489.  1369.  1378.]]
```

This is one extracted band from pix file. I have three bands. Here I am trying combine this bands:

```
rgbArray = np.zeros((rows,cols,3), dtype=np.uint8)
band1 = dataset.GetRasterBand(closest_channel(dict_channel, 640)-1)
band2 = dataset.GetRasterBand(closest_channel(dict_channel, 550)-1)
band3 = dataset.GetRasterBand(closest_channel(dict_channel, 460)-1)
data1 = band1.ReadAsArray (0, 0, cols, rows).astype(np.float)
data2 = band2.ReadAsArray (0, 0, cols, rows).astype(np.float)
data3 = band3.ReadAsArray (0, 0, cols, rows).astype(np.float)
rgbArray[..., 0] = data1
rgbArray[..., 1] = data2
rgbArray[..., 2] = data3
img = Image.fromarray(rgbArray, 'RGB')
```

and the picture looks like this:
[image]

Of course it is not good result. It should be picture taking from plane on the ground where should be field.

I will be very glad for any, any help
Thanks a lot

Comment: `data1`, `data2` and `data3` are floating point arrays, but `rgbArray` is `uint8`.  You should convert the floating point arrays to the range (0, 255) before assigned them to `rbgArray`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the same thing as memoselyk mentioned. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the domain of your data, you scale it to be in a range [0, 255].

A naive approach, would be to consider the range of your data, the maximum range of the signal, e.g.

```
[...]

data1 = band1.ReadAsArray (0, 0, cols, rows).astype(np.float)

[...]

# Normalize data range
max1 = np.nanmax(data1)
min1 = np.nanmax(data1)

data1 = ((data1 - min1)/(max1 - min1)) * 255

[...]  

rgbArray[..., 0] = data1.astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I was trying multiply data1 with 255 but I didn't try combination of min - values. The picture looks good, but it is a little dark. Should I use alpha channel for lighten image a little?

Comment: No... the alpha channel has a different purpose. The correct approach would be to [increase the brightness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11163652/5509239) of the image.

Comment: Thanks it is not looking easy, but I will try this.

Comment: Option 1 is doing [the conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278323) yourself, manipulating the data and converting it back. Option 2 is using [a library](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html) or a [tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast).

Comment: Now it is look more better. Really thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Memoselyk I am trying increase brightness. So I try convert rgb to hsv. Using matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv. Then I use histogram equalization - code is here: http://pastebin.com/79L2dBJn And then convert back to RGB. When I try it with grayscale image, it is ok. Looks like on Wikipedia histogram equalization website. But when I try code on Value/luminance, image is quite overexposed (please look http://imgur.com/XTveKo1). I will be very glad for your help. I made a new thread, so if you know answer I send you a link to get some points.