# Lighten the picture

Tags: image, image-processing

We know that if we want to lighten the picture, the simplest way it to scale the matrix by some scalar value ( >1 ).

But when the picture is read in the integer mode (unit8), some entries of the scaled matrix may exceed the maximal value(255).

**Q**: How do you deal with such cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just bound it.
Example (pseudo code):-

```
unsigned char input = ...;
float brightnessMagic=1.3f;
float output =   min(input*brightnessMagic,255);
return (unsigned char)output;
```

If you want more like 1:1 mapping, [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) may help.
However, I think it is overkill.

Related question : [Algorithm to modify brightness for RGB image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163578/algorithm-to-modify-brightness-for-rgb-image)